# Wait until inner promise resolves before returning

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a function that is returning a null value instead of waiting for the inner promise to resolve before returning.

I've tried using async/await, but wasn't successful. The getTargets function needs to return upload_url, not a promise.

```
    function getTargets (currentChunk) {
        let chunkArray = [];

        // split chunk strings into key value pairs, then add them to an array
        for(let parameter of currentChunk) {
            let keyValue = parameter.split('=');
            chunkArray[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
        }

        for(let file of myFiles) {
            if (file.name === chunkArray['resumableFilename']) {
                myService.getUploadUrl(file.id, chunkArray['resumableChunkNumber'], file.upload_id).then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.upload_url);
                    return response.upload_url;
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "The getTargets function needs to return upload_url, not a promise." -> I want to read tomorows newspaper ...

Comment: Just return the promise maybe?! `return myService.getUploadUrl(...).then(...)`

Comment: The plugin that calls this function requires a url, not a promise.

Comment: Then that has to be part of the question :) thats your real problem.

Comment: It already does. See "The getTargets function needs to return upload_url, not a promise."

Comment: And thats impossible. You need a different solution depending on your exact usecase.